# Replace all words that start with '@@@id' using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have to replace all words in a string that start with '@@@id' with "".

eg-:
`s = "@@@id_2_1_4 test @@@_2 test @@@id_3_1_4 test"`
then it should become 
 `s = "test @@@_2 test test`

I tried using `re.sub("/(@@@id\S+)", '', s)`  but it doesn't work.
What will be the correct way for it??

Comment: Remove `/` char at the start: `re.sub(r'\s*@@@id\S+', '', s).strip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import re
s = "@@@id_2_1_4 test @@@_2 test @@@id_3_1_4 test"
print(re.sub(r'\s*@@@id\S+', '', s).strip())
```

Output:

```
test @@@_2 test test
```